# css unordered list inside table column non-wrapping elements in wrapping container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an unordered list inside a bootstrap table column styled such that with html like

```
<td>
    <ul class="mylist">
        <li>A list item</li>
        <li>Another list item</li>
        <li>And another</li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

I end up with something that looks like

> A list... Another...
>
> And ano...

With breaking between `li` elements as needed but not necessarily after every `li`

I've tried doing it with `div` elements and with `ul` and `li` as above with the following css

```
ul.mylist {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.mylist li {
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 4em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

What I end up with though does not add the ellipsis, so I have something like

> A list item Another list item
>
> And another

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add this to a codepen or jsbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by modifying the css and including span elements to truncate the list length and add the ellipsis if needed.

```
<td>
    <ul class="mylist">
        <li><span class="mylist-el-short">A list item</span></li>
        <li><span class="mylist-el-short">Another list item</span></li>
        <li><span class="mylist-el-short">And another</span></li>
    </ul>
</td>

ul.mylist {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.mylist li {
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

span.mylist-el-short {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 4em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```